# Showing a PDF File in a page which name was obtained from a PL Package?

Tags: file, servlets

I'm working for an e-business company and my project leader gave me this use case... I have to call a PL Package (I know How to do it) and, with the output parameter (pdf file name), I have to look up a file in a server and show it in a page... Can anyone give an idea ?... Thanxk !

Comment: search in google "servlet download file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4629 (after search in google "servlet download file"):

```
private void doDownload( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp,
                         String filename, String original_filename )
    throws IOException
{
    File                f        = new File(filename);
    int                 length   = 0;
    ServletOutputStream op       = resp.getOutputStream();
    ServletContext      context  = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
    String              mimetype = context.getMimeType( filename );

    //
    //  Set the response and go!
    //
    //
    resp.setContentType( (mimetype != null) ? mimetype : "application/octet-stream" );
    resp.setContentLength( (int)f.length() );
    resp.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + original_filename + "\"" );

    //
    //  Stream to the requester.
    //
    byte[] bbuf = new byte[BUFSIZE];
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));

    while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1))
    {
        op.write(bbuf,0,length);
    }

    in.close();
    op.flush();
    op.close();
}
```